# Eclipse Warnings: Possible Cause of Breakpoint Issue?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm getting several Eclipse "warnings" and I think they might be causing the issue I'm having in another post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550417/cannot-reach-breakpoint

I have two questions:

1. The person who answered my other post seems to think it has to do with my position values - could the reason I cannot reach the breakpoint be related to one of these warnings instead? The viewpager does not function - I cannot set a breakpoint at it - and I'm getting several warnings regarding it.
2. How can they be resolved? (ensuring I reach the breakpoint - not simply removing the non functional code: I need it to work)

Basically I need to figure out what in my current source is causing my non functional viewpager and the inability to set a breakpoint at it in the current source below:

### Eclipse Warnings:

```
The method onTabChanged(PagerAdapter, int, int) from the type Home.ImagePagerAdapter is never used locally:

is occurring on the line: protected void onTabChanged(final PagerAdapter adapter,



 The value of the field Home.ImagePagerAdapter.stringArray is not used:

is occurring on the line: private String[] stringArray = new String[] { "vevo",


 The constructor Home.ImagePagerAdapter(Activity, int[], String[]) is never used locally:

is occurring on the line: public ImagePagerAdapter(Activity act, int[] mImages,



 Multiple markers at this line
    - The value of the local variable mPageChangeListener is 
     not used
    - The value of the local variable mPageChangeListener is 
     not used:

is occurring on the line:    final ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener mPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
```

### JAVA

```
public class Home extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements

VideoClickListener {
    // A reference to our list that will hold the video details
    private VideosListView listView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    public static final String API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "o7VVHhK9zf0";
    private int mCurrentTabPosition = NO_CURRENT_POSITION;
    private static final int NO_CURRENT_POSITION = -1;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerListView;
    private String[] drawerListViewItems;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    ScrollView mainScrollView;
    Button fav_up_btn1;
    Button fav_dwn_btn1;
    String TAG = "DEBUG THIS";
    String playlist = "burtonbcell3";
    Activity activity;
    int imageArray[];
    String[] stringArray;

    private OnPageChangeListener mPageChangeListener;
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
        drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
        drawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
        R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
        R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
        );
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        listView = (VideosListView) findViewById(R.id.videosListView);
        listView.setOnVideoClickListener(this);
        new GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(responseHandler, playlist).execute();
        setOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangeListener);
        final ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener mPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                onTabChanged(mPager.getAdapter(), mCurrentTabPosition, position);
                position = mCurrentTabPosition;
                int oldPos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                if (position > oldPos) {

                    System.out.print(position);
                    // Moving to the right
                    String playlist = "TheMozARTGROUP‎";
                    new GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(responseHandler, playlist)
                            .execute();

                    View vg = findViewById(R.layout.home);
                    vg.invalidate();

                } else if (position < oldPos) {
                    // Moving to the Left
                    System.out.print(position);
                    String playlist = "TheMozARTGROUP‎";
                    new GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(responseHandler, playlist)
                            .execute();

                    View vg = findViewById(R.layout.home);
                    vg.invalidate();

                }
            }

            private void onTabChanged(PagerAdapter adapter,
                    int mCurrentTabPosition, int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

    }

    private void setOnPageChangeListener(
            OnPageChangeListener mPageChangeListener2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    Handler responseHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            populateListWithVideos(msg);
        };
    };

    private void populateListWithVideos(Message msg) {
        Library lib = (Library) msg.getData().get(
                GetYouTubeUserVideosTask.LIBRARY);
        listView.setVideos(lib.getVideos());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        responseHandler = null;
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoClicked(Video video) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Player.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", video.getId());
        intent.putExtra("title", video.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("uploader", video.getUploader());
        intent.putExtra("viewCount", video.getviewCount());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        public ImagePagerAdapter(Activity act, int[] mImages,
                String[] stringArra) {
            imageArray = mImages;
            activity = act;
            stringArray = stringArra;
        }

        // this is your constructor
        public ImagePagerAdapter() {
            super();

        }

        private int[] mImages = new int[] { R.drawable.selstation_up_btn,
                R.drawable.classical_up_btn, R.drawable.country_up_btn,
                R.drawable.dance_up_btn, R.drawable.hiphop_up_btn,
                R.drawable.island_up_btn, R.drawable.latin_up_btn,
                R.drawable.pop_up_btn, R.drawable.samba_up_btn };

        private String[] stringArray = new String[] { "vevo",
                "TheMozARTGROUP‎", "TimMcGrawVEVO‎", "TiestoVEVO‎",
                "EminemVEVO‎" };

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mImages.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = Home.this;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }

        protected void onTabChanged(final PagerAdapter adapter,
                final int oldPosition, final int newPosition) {
            // Calc if swipe was left to right, or right to left
            if (oldPosition > newPosition) {
                // left to right
            } else {
                // right to left


            }
            final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **If you get XXX is never used locally**, it means that you can safely remove the method XXX.
   The first warning means that you have some unused code in your class. This may decrease the readability of your whole code.
2. **If you get YYY is not used**, you can safely remove the variable YYY from your code. Declaring variable and don't use them increase the memory consumption of your application. Since its an android app, you should have a special look at the memory usage of your program.

Comment: I understand that... that is all correct if the code works and you are left over with these warnings - my problem is different - I have a part of my code that should be working but isn't - and I think these errors are related to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550417/cannot-reach-breakpoint

Comment: I also posted two questions - and although you provided two answers - you didn't answer either question

Comment: I appreciate your feedback though! (feel free to edit your answer - I just edited my post a bit)

Comment: For completeness, not having a static reference to a method/variable/etc doesn't necessarily mean it's safe to remove, since things can be referenced via reflection, either directly, through a library, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct solution to your problem. However, I suggest you comment out all unused code to get rid of your warnings. If your code still doesn't work correctly, you have at least ruled out commented out code causing problems. By the way, those aren't errors, they are warnings. Unlike errors, warnings can be ignored (although I wouldn't). Whenever I see warnings, I suspect the author hasn't throughly thought through the design at that location and may need to be re-thought.